# UWP Windows 10: How to check if device has a camera?

Tags: c#, windows, camera, uwp, webcam

i currently plan a UWP App for Windows 10 with a Barcode Scanner inside. For Barcode scanning the device needs a camera, but the app can be used without the scanner as well. 
So first I want to check wheather the device has a Webcam or not. If the device has a camera, then it should continue and open the Barcode scanner, if not then it should show show an error message and return to the main page.

The scanner already works fine but I dont know how to ask the device if it has a camera. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Note the question in the duplicate link isn't identical but the example in the answer there answers this question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!